# Twig batch with condition

Tags: symfony, twig

I send Cards(some data) from controller to twig and create row with 3 elems.

```
{% for elem in Cards|batch(3) %}
    <div>
        <div class="row">
        {% include ':appviews/elements/Card:Card.html.twig' with {'elem': elem} %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

It works well, but now i need to add card with static html (not from Data), that must be rendered one time. 
Is there way, to add only 2 elems in row for the first loop?

```
{% for elem in Cards|batch(3) %}
     <div>
         <div class="row">
             {% if loop.first %}
                <div class="col-md-4 noPadding margin">
                    <div class="square"> SOME TEXT</div>
                </div>
             {% endif %}
             {% include ':appviews/elements/Card:Card.html.twig' with {'elem': elem} %}
         </div>
     </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with "batch" filter. I suggest you use some logical tricks. There can be many of them, depending on:

- how often do you want to insert the hardcoded block
- how much code/template piece is being reused

For example, if you only need this once in the beginning, you can slice your array once, and then slice it again:

```
{% for elem in Cards|slice(0, 1) %}
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            {% if loop.first %}
                <div class="col-md-4 noPadding margin">
                    <div class="square"> SOME TEXT</div>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
            {% include ':appviews/elements/Card:Card.html.twig' with {'elem': elem} %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}

{% for elem in Cards|slice(2, Cards|length) %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

If you think there's too much copy/paste going on, you can create a macro for the "row", with some parameters and have all the logic in it. Then you can control, how, when and what is rendered. But this can be an overload in simple cases, so you decide:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html

Comment: Thank you! Solution is almost ready, but i have some problem at line 6-8. Dump works, but Include does not work! How it can't be? 
https://codeshare.io/rMuAf

Comment: I'm not familiar with such Symfony referencing: include ':appviews/elements/questCard:questCard.html.twig' See the documentation and fix the path: http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/best_practices/templates.html#template-locations http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/book/templating.html#referencing-templates-in-a-bundle PS. I would still suggest you to use macro instead of include. It is going to be completely the same code, but easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Well, final code is:

```
<div class="row rowQuest">
    <div class="col-md-4 noPadding margin">
        <div class="square">HARDCODED CARD</div>
    </div>
    {% set firstPartOfQuests = quests|slice(0,2) %}
    {% for elem in firstPartOfQuests|batch(2) %}
        {% include 'appviews/elements/questCard/questCard.html.twig' with {'elem': elem} %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% set lastPartOfQuests = quests|slice(2,quests|length) %}
{% for elem in lastPartOfQuests|batch(3) %}
    <div class="row rowQuest">
{% include ':appviews/elements/questCard:questCard.html.twig' with {'elem': elem} %}
     </div>
{% endfor %}
```

PS i still don't understand why i can't use for cycle without batch.

```
{% for elem in first2Quests %}
    {% include 'appviews/elements/questCard/questCard.html.twig' with     {'elem': elem} %}
{% endfor %}
```